# Typescript Generic with in keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to know why with `T1`, I cannot get the same type as `{ a: string, b: number, c: boolean }`? The `-?` is not working without a Generic. It only works with a Generic.

```
type Item = { a: string, b: number | undefined, c: boolean };
type T1 = { [P in keyof Item]-?: Item[P] };  // { a: string, b: number | undefined, c: boolean }
type T2<U> = { [P in keyof U]-?: U[P] };  // { a: string, b: number, c: boolean }
const t2: T2<Item> = {
    a: 'abc',
    b: 123,
    c: false
}
```

Comment: I think your assumption here is wrong.  `T2<Item>` still has `b` with `| undefined`  ( adding `{} &` before the mapped type makes the type more clear) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAkiKBbGBeGBvGBDAXDAZxACcBLAOwHMAaGAI33IFck6piYAfGJ8gEygAzClD60AxvjoB7aQBso2cjAC+AblCRYAFQCMaTDADaABRgUYAayhhpg+IiQBdALQB+fAmSmnqtTBgAekDDPEISChp6RhY2Dm5eAWFyUQkpWQUlVU1oGG0AJgAeAFUAPgMMFRgAMkNTc2VrW3ti1w8YYp8-GGBxaXIiGBB8-ALCryRy9CwgkKwwojIqWgYYZlZ2Lh5+IRExGEl6DMVlYACAsIBybDpxS+oz89XE3ZSxR4DDwWw5AihgFRAA

Comment: Also worth noting that `b: number | undefined` is not the same as `b?: number`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I think you find the exactly wrong part!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `b?: number` and `b: number|undefined` are not equivalent. You can refer to the example below. When `b: number|undefined` is changed to `b?: number`, it will work normally . For the example of `b: number|undefined`, the use of `T2<Item>` must have the `b` attribute cannot explain the problem, because when only `{ a: string, b: number | undefined, c: boolean}` is used, the `b` attribute must also exist. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gDRQBGA-LqQK4I0SHUDGuNA9rwBsImUlAC+AbgBQoSFAAqARhTooAbQAKUMlADWEELwBmseAgC6AWganEm8+IlQoAeheqc+ImSq1GLNkIoAB8oJlIAEwgjMggIrh5+IRFxGXBoeQAmAB4AVQA+FQxNbVF9QxNcqxtc+0dnNw9cAhIKahp-VnYE2iThUTEpTl5SAihgTNws7LhEQtQ0KWdnTwByTBpOVcol5Y6oRUyAZh3lqG4oI0wBPAgpQaGRseAjqeUF3ZXcdc3tz78DsdTssLlcbncHo0NIReJBCKAoKsaKttHgoAhiHg8D5SuN0oiMJ4Wj4nKDrrcnGIUTQmMAoIQIABHJjEBkRXGyaCrQnNbwUJz7ZhdIKhcJRGKkOKkxKCfqU1YAOkeozpwAALLgeV5Wr5BQF2CEwpForF4ucZckBkV-msNltgc4yeD7kA)

```js
type Item = { a: string, b?: number, c: boolean };
type T1 = { [P in keyof Item]-?: Item[P] };  // { a: string, b: number | undefined, c: boolean }
type T2<U> = { [P in keyof U]-?: U[P] };  // { a: string, b: number, c: boolean }
const t2: T2<Item> = {
    a: 'abc',
    b: 123,
    c: false
}

const t3: T1 = {
    a: 'abc',
    b: 123,
    c: false
}

// Property 'b' is missing in type '{ a: string; c: false; }' but required in type '{ a: string; b: number | undefined; c: boolean; }'.
const t4: { a: string, b: number | undefined, c: boolean } = {
    a: 'abc',
    c: false
}
```